# Фоновая картинка на всё разрешение окна?

Tags: css, css3

Как это делается или как называется ? 
Пример-http://vse-gotovo.com/

Когда заходишь на сайт там на весь фон окна у меня их картинка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/12/02/120203e0-f7d1-4731-9a6c-be3c458c6ce9.jpg?n=Resident-Evil-2_GLP-Page-Hero-1084_1920x600.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Тут указываем источник картинки ссылку или путь в скобках.

```
background-image: url(https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/12/02/120203e0-f7d1-4731-9a6c-be3c458c6ce9.jpg?n=Resident-Evil-2_GLP-Page-Hero-1084_1920x600.jpg);
```

Тут указываем размер. cover - картинка маштабируется на весь экран/блок сохроняя свои пропорции.

```
background-size: cover;
```

Тут указываем повторяется или нет.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Тут указываем выравнивание по Х и У. В данном случае указано center. Но, можно указать в %.

```
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
```

Фиксируем

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://placeimg.com/500/300/an");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.block1 {min-height: 400px;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block1">следующий блок</div>
```